# como funciona o browsing-context (contexto de navegação)

Tags: html5

Estava lendo a documentação do atributo [`target` do elemento HTML `<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target):

> (...) No HTML5, é um nome ou palavra-chave que se refere a um *contexto de navegação* (por exemplo, aba, janela ou um frame) (...)

O que é um contexto de navegação e como ele funciona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O contexto de navegação pode ser entendido como uma instância (ou sessão) do navegador, pode ser uma janela, uma aba ou um `<iframe>`, com histórico de navegação independente.

No HTML 5 um contexto é criado ao definir um `<iframe>` com o atributo `name` ou clicar em um *link* ou enviar um formulário com o atributo `target` definido diferente dos valores especiais (`_self`, `_blank`, etc.).

#### Exemplo de funcionamento:

Nota: é preciso salvar o conteúdo em um arquivo HTML pois não funciona corretamente direto no site devido a restrições.

Clique no primeiro link, ele vai abrir em nova guia (criou um novo contexto), volte para a aba e clique no segundo link que será aberto na mesma guia do primeiro link. Pois ambos os links o tem o atributo `target` com valor `meu-contexto`.

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/" target="meu-contexto">StackOverflow pt</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="meu-contexto">StackOverflow en</a></li>
</ol>
```

---

O nome do contexto atual pode ser acessado pela propriedade Javascript `window.name`. Modificar essa propriedade pode desvincular o contexto atual do contexto pai. É possível criar um vinculo modificando essa propriedade apenas quando uma relação pai/filho, como é o caso do `<iframe>`.

Documentação relacionada: http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/browsers.html#browsing-context